# Authlogic + Factory Girl: Validation failed: Password is too short (minimum is 4 characters)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, authlogic

I'm trying to build a factory for an "account" model defined with authlogic:

```
class Account < UuidEnabled
  acts_as_authentic  do |c|
    c.validate_password_field = true
    c.require_password_confirmation = true
    c.ignore_blank_passwords = false
    c.crypto_provider = Authlogic::CryptoProviders::Sha512
  end
end
```

This is my factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :account do
    sequence(:email) { |n| "account_#{n}@example.com"}
    password = "1234"
    password_confirmation { |a| a.password} # to make things work even if the password is changed
  end
end
```

My test fails with

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Password is too short (minimum is 4 characters), Password confirmation is too short (minimum is 4 characters)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think this is just a typo, try:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :account do
    sequence(:email) { |n| "account_#{n}@example.com"}
    password "1234"
    password_confirmation { |a| a.password} # to make things work even if the password is changed
  end
end
```

Note that the equals sign after `password` has been removed

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `attr_accessible :password` in the Account model?

Comment: nope, because the previous answer solved my problem :)